# couchdb variable session timeouts

Tags: couchdb, session-timeout

Is there a way in couchdb to set different session timeout values for different users, for instance based on the `role` of the user?

The documentation at http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/config/auth.html#couch_httpd_auth/timeout suggests that one value will be used universally, but I'm hoping I've missed something.